# Windows user cannot connect via application, but can via Remote Desktop

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, remote-access

I have an application (ASG-Zena) giving an 1385 error (Logon failure: the user has not been granted the requested logon type at this computer) when trying to run a batch job.

I have checked on

1. "Access this computer from the network" includes Everyone and Administrators and many others.
2. "Deny access to this computer from the network" make sure that Guest is not listed there. If you still have problems, then maybe make sure that nothing is listed there.
3. Administrative tools...local security policy..security options
   "Network access sharing and security model for local accounts" there
   are 2 options either classic or 'guest only'.  Mine is set to classic.

(These diagnostics come from this [post](http://forums.techarena.in/windows-xp-support/71497.htm))

The account in question is added to the Administrator group on this computer.  I know the login is valid because I regularly login to the server via remote Desktop.  What other settings should I check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer through comparing servers that work to ones that didn't.

The account you wish to logon as must be listed under the `Logon as Batch` setting.  The `Logon as Batch` setting can be found in Local Security Settings under Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment.